# Linq Where clause to generate List based on results of a different List

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net

I am trying to generate a `List<Object>` using `Where` clause with properties from a different `List<Object>`. I know that I could use a `.Include()`, similar to a SQL join if I were using Entity Framework but I am not using Entity Framework so I don't think it would work. I have:

```
List<Problem> problems = MethodToCallDbAndGenerateList();  //ado.net
problems = problems.Where(x => x.Property1 == "value").ToList();
//remaining logic

List<Solved> solved = MethodToCallDb()
                      .Where(x => x.SolvedId == problems.ProblemId)
                      .ToList();
             //error happens in Where(...problems.ProblemId);
         //List<Problem> does not contain a definition for ProblemId
```

The error says the `List<Problem>` does not contain `ProblemId` but I do have that property in my class. So I am unsure of why I am getting that error.

How can I generate my `List<Solved>` based on filtered results from

`.Where(x => x.SolvedId == problems.SolvedId);`

Comment: In C# types are everything. The type of `problems` is `List<Problem>`. The class `List<T>` does not have a property called `ProblemId`. Individual members of the `List<Problem>` are of class `Problem`, they may well have that property, but that has nothing to do with `List<T>`. So what are you trying to test against a collection of `Problem`s stored in a `List<T>`?

Comment: I think you just answered my question. I will have to look at it later but Im guessing that I will be able to loop through and have `.Where(.....problems.ElementAt(i).ProblemId);`
I will need to index it and get a single of instance of `Problem.ProblemId`.

Comment: In C# that would be `problems[i].ProblemId` but you may also what to consider either `problems.Any()` or `problems.All()` depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Okay thanks. You led me in the right direction. Basically without using Entity Framework and not using `.Include()` I am basically trying to perform a join on two tables from my db. With ef I could do `_context.Problem.Include(x => x.Solved).ToList()` but I am not using ef, so I complicatingly trying to do something similar with two separate `List`

Comment: LINQ to object supports join just like EF - you can use `Join` or in query syntax `join`...`in`...`equals`...`to`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LINQ to Objects, you can use the `Enumerable.Join` method to create a join between two `List<T>`s and just return the matching members:

```
List<Problem> problems = MethodToCallDbAndGenerateList()
                            .Where(x => x.Property1 == "value")
                            .ToList();

List<Solved> solved = MethodToCallDb()
                      .Join(problems, s => s.SolvedId, p => p.ProblemId, (s,p) => s)
                      .ToList();
```

However, if there are a lot of `problems` and `solved`, or if you frequently check the same list of `problems`, or if you are only creating `problems` to use in the `join`, you'd be better off creating a `HashSet`:

```
var problemIDs = problems.Select(p => p.ProblemId).ToHashSet();

List<Solved> solved = MethodToCallDb()
                      .Where(s => problemIDs.Contains(s.SolvedId))
                      .ToList();
```

NOTE: If you are only creating `problems` to use in the join, better to skip creating the `List<Problem>` and just do:

```
var problemIDs = MethodToCallDbAndGenerateList()
                    .Where(x => x.Property1 == "value")
                    .Select(p => p.ProblemId)
                    .ToHashSet();
```

Comment: Thanks I did not know about the Enumerable.Join. The ToHashSet() is a good idea too.

Comment: @jah LINQ to objects has almost all the capabilities of LINQ to databases and more; it also works with query syntax as well as fluent syntax.